# What's the most efficient method of transferring gold between characters?

Tags: torchlight-2

Aside from tranferring all your gold to a friend who will then tranfer it to your new player, it appears that the only way to transfer gold is by buying items that have a higher sell rate and transferring them to your new account.  However, this is just not practical as 1) resell value on items is terrible and 2) you're limited to how much your shared stash can hold.

Is there any other way to transfer gold to another account that doesn't involve chesting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this mod ([[NPC] KelinTor's Merchant +9 Quests + Mercenaries V1.38](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=45811#p415450)) , if you like.

It contains what I think is a fairly inventive way of doing it.

> 'KelinTor's Merchant' now sell 'Deposit scroll'
>   for 5000 gold (stackable), then use it to transform into '5000 gold
>   coins' (stackable),you can put it in your shared stash. Your other
>   character take it and can sell the coins for 5000 gold. The General
>   goods merchant now sell 'Deposit scroll100000' for 100'000 gold
>   (stackable), then use it to transform into 'Stash of gold'
>   (stackable),you can put it in your shared stash. Your other character
>   take it and can sell the coins for 100000 gold.